# Magento 2.3 multi currencies without using exchange rate conversion

Tags: product, magento2.3, multicurrency, currency-rates

I'm trying to find a solution for my client which is to set products price in multi-currency manually not using base currency and exchange rate conversion.

Please share your thought, solutions, and recommend extensions.

I appreciate all of your advice and answers.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To set up multiple currencies on Magento 2 follow this step:

1. Setup currency: Move to menu Stores >> Configuration. Under the GENERAL tab you will find the sub-menu Currency Setup. Setup Currency Options with what you need and click Save Config.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/btrr1.png
2. Setup currency rates: Move menu to Stores >> Currency Rates. Set value for all parameters and hit Saves Currency Rates
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWqnc.png

That's all, you will see a dropdown on your front
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqVGM.png

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your answer but my question is " How to use multi-currency without using auto conversion rate?" .I want to set some products price for different currency manually not using base currency.

Comment: Magento has built-in functionality for currency conversion. In your case need to change some code to be able to set up